# Checking dates against a .properties file

Tags: performance, datetime, bash, shell

I am writing a script that will check the set values against a .properties file and I am just wondering if there is any nicer way to write what I have here.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# @summary Check Values 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function _RunChecks
{
SuccessfulDiffRun="true" 
timestamp() { date +"%F"; }
TodaysDate=$(timestamp)
#Read savedState.properties file
while read LINE; do eval $LINE; done < savedState.properties
#Compare the Values
echo "HotPatch : "
if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP" ]; then
    echo Dates Are A Match : TodaysDate:$TodaysDate = HotpatchRunDate:$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP
    if [ "$SuccessfulDiffRun" = "$WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS" ]; then
        echo SuccessfulDiffRun : $WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS
        echo Hotpatch Run Was Successful 
    else
        echo SuccessfulDiffRun : $WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS
        echo Exiting
        exit 0
    fi
else
    echo Dates Not A Match: TodaysDate:$TodaysDate = HotpatchRunDate:$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP
    exit 0 
fi
echo ""
echo "RC Prod  : "
if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP" ]; then
    echo Dates Are A Match : TodaysDate:$TodaysDate = RCRunDate:$WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP
    if [ "$SuccessfulDiffRun" = "$WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS" ]; then
        echo SuccessfulDiffRun : $WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS
        echo RC Run Was Successful
    else
        echo SuccessfulDiffRun : $WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS
        echo Exiting
        exit 0
    fi
else
    echo Dates Not A Match: TodaysDate:$TodaysDate = HotpatchRunDate:$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP
    exit 0 
fi
}
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# @summary Start
_RunChecks
```

Comment: The title says you want to tidy it up. The tag says you want performance. Which one of these has your preference?

Comment: @Mast well performance first I guess, then clean up

Comment: If you're really concerned about performance, bash is the wrong language.

Answer (score 4):

#### Security concerns

Judging by the eval, it seems the properties file contains assignment statements that bash understands. Or so you think. Using eval this way is most often a serious security risk. What if somebody fobs a way to tamper with the file and append a line like this:

```
bash /tmp/evilscript.sh
```

Not only the evil script will get executed by whoever is the effective user (hopefully not root), you will not even realize it happened.

Even if you're not particularly concerned by security issues (dangerous mindset though), it's just not worth the risk. One way to make this safer is to match the live against the expected format using the `[[...]]` built-in, or similar.

#### Performance

It seems there are just two lines to parse. At this scale, I doubt performance is a serious concern, or that alternative approaches would make a noticeable difference.

#### Simplify

I find the way you compare the previous and current values of the two variables overly tedious. I would take a much simpler, lazier approach. For example, keep a copy of the previous version of the file at a place not editable by its current users, and replace the tedious checks for each variable with a simple `diff`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks good already, written neatly. But there's room for more indentation. Indentation is the key to making your code look nice. Whenever you enter a certain, start indenting. Though most of the IDEs do it for you.

And use white space. You are never going to run out of space as much as you use it. So isolate pieces of code whenever necessary with some space.

Comment: You're using an IDE for [tag:bash]? I think you're referring to a text editor.

Comment: @Mast some consider `emacs` to be an IDE, no? :p

Answer (score 3):

**Don't repeat yourself**.

The `HotPatch` and `RC Prod` sequences are suspiciously similar, and you already facing the double maintenance problem:

```
    echo Dates Not A Match: TodaysDate:$TodaysDate = HotpatchRunDate:$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP
```

at line 40 should read

```
    echo Dates Not A Match: TodaysDate:$TodaysDate = RCRunDate:$WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP
```

Better make them into function.

Along the same line,

```
    echo SuccessfulDiffRun : $whatever
```

is identical in both `if` and `else` clauses, hence should be moved out of conditional.